# Even though I'm adding 1 to the UI_score, why isn't the score_counter updating?

Tags: python, printing, updates

```
UI_score = 0
player_score = 0
score_counter = str(UI_score) + "-" + str(player_score)
UI_score += 1
print(score_counter)
```

The score_counter is still giving me 0-0, when it should give me 1-0. Why is this happening?

Comment: Python works with strings and integers by evaluating them when the line of code is called. On the third line, you're setting `score_counter` to the value of UI and player score when the line is run. On the next line, you update the `UI_score` but not the score_counter. You must run that line again in order to update to the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update the variable after using the old value, try this instead:

```
UI_score = 0
player_score = 0
UI_score += 1
score_counter = str(UI_score) + "-" + str(player_score)
print(score_counter)
```